# Display all people and their primary phone/email when available (and be able to edit it)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-view

I want to display a list of my contact people within MS Access form.
Every person can have more phone numbers and e-mails, one of which is always marked as the primary one.

Therefore I have:

- tblPeople
- tblEmails (PersonID INT, IsPrimary BIT)
- tblPhoneNumbers (PersonID INT, IsPrimary BIT)

Now I have a data entry form with my customers (companies). There is a data entry subform with people associated with this customer.

Next to each person, I want to display their primary phone number and e-mail, if it exists. This field should actually control the record in tblPhoneNumbers. So if it doesn't exist, the fields will be blank, but if I type something in, it will actually create a record within tblPhoneNumbers or tblEmails and mark it as primary.

I imagine that triggers will need to be used, but I am struggling with displaying the information what so ever. I tried this:

```
CREATE VIEW v_DE_CustomerPeople
AS
    SELECT  A.PersonID,
            A.CustomerID,
            A.NationalityID,
            A.GenderID,
            A.CommunicationLanguageID,
            A.FirstName,
            A.LastName,
            A.TitleBefore,
            A.TitleAfter,
            A.JobTitle,
            B.PhoneNumber,
            A.IsOnMailingList,
            A.Notes
    FROM tbl1CustomerPeople A   LEFT JOIN tbl1PhoneNumbers  B ON A.PersonID = B.PersonID
    WHERE B.IsPrimary = 1
;
```

This accomplishes to display the person, IF they have a primary phone number associated. But I would like to display a NULL value in the phone fields instead and be able to type it in and create that phone number record.

Is this possible?

Comment: Recommended reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Why do you `LEFT JOIN` to `tbl1PhoneNumbers` when you have `WHERE B.IsPrimary = 1`? It is *impossible* for `IsPrimary` to have the value `1` if not row was found.

Comment: Because I'm struggling and that's why I'm asking for help :)

Comment: I didn't ask why you're asking for help, I asked why use a `LEFT JOIN` when a row *must* be returned. Why not use an `INNER JOIN`, when that's effectively what you have? If you want a `NULL` where the row isn't round, then the clause in the `WHERE` actually be in the `ON`.

Comment: Move your WHERE clause condition into the JOIN clause.

Comment: I think you better use form/subform/subsubform. Or this technique https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp#:~:text=We%20synchronize%20the%20subforms%20using%20the%20Link%20Child,based%20on%20a%20control%20on%20the%20main%20form.